# Why not calling save() on one model, while calling on another

Tags: python, django

I am learning django from [tangowithdjango](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/). I am trying to understand the code of `populate_rango.py`. 
Code is:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'tango_with_django_project.settings')

import django
django.setup()

from rango.models import Category, Page


def populate():
    python_cat = add_cat('Python')

    add_page(cat=python_cat,
        title="Official Python Tutorial",
        url="http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/")

    add_page(cat=python_cat,
        title="How to Think like a Computer Scientist",
        url="http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/")

    add_page(cat=python_cat,
        title="Learn Python in 10 Minutes",
        url="http://www.korokithakis.net/tutorials/python/")

    django_cat = add_cat("Django")

    add_page(cat=django_cat,
        title="Official Django Tutorial",
        url="https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/")

    add_page(cat=django_cat,
        title="Django Rocks",
        url="http://www.djangorocks.com/")

    add_page(cat=django_cat,
        title="How to Tango with Django",
        url="http://www.tangowithdjango.com/")

    frame_cat = add_cat("Other Frameworks")

    add_page(cat=frame_cat,
        title="Bottle",
        url="http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/")

    add_page(cat=frame_cat,
        title="Flask",
        url="http://flask.pocoo.org")

    # Print out what we have added to the user.
    for c in Category.objects.all():
        for p in Page.objects.filter(category=c):
            print "- {0} - {1}".format(str(c), str(p))

def add_page(cat, title, url, views=0):
    p = Page.objects.get_or_create(category=cat, title=title)[0]
    p.url=url
    p.views=views
    p.save()
    return p

def add_cat(name):
    c = Category.objects.get_or_create(name=name)[0]
    return c

# Start execution here!
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Starting Rango population script..."
    populate()
```

What am I unable to understand is, the add_cat function doesn't call save:

```
def add_cat(name):
c = Category.objects.get_or_create(name=name)[0]
return c
```

while, add_page calls p.save():

```
def add_page(cat, title, url, views=0):
    p = Page.objects.get_or_create(category=cat, title=title)[0]
    p.url = url
    p.views = views
    p.save()
    return p
```

Please explain this to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`add_cat` function calls `get_or_create`, which mean if your database has the same entry with name match, then just return the instance, otherwise create one. It returns a tuple. First element is the instance, second element is a boolean which indicates whether the result is a creation of new instance or not.

`add_page` on the other hand, calls `get_or_create` as well as `save`, but it goes with the logic that `add_page` needs. The `save` in `add_page` means:
"I have this page now, regardless if it's a new page or an existing page, but I'm going to update the `url` and the `views` on it and save the result". `add_cat` only need to create `Category`, not updating anything. Every time you update an existing instance, you need to call `save` to save the changes.

Check django doc about [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create), it explains everything you need to know.

Comment: Doesn't add_page also call get_or_create?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean, yea `add_page` does call `get_or_create`, so what's your question?

Comment: As I stated, p.save() is called but not c.save().

Comment: So, it means creation of the category object doesn't require save method while add_page does updation apart from creation, so it does require save method.

Comment: That's partially right. But sometimes create an instance DO need to call `save()`, it's just that your code sample choose to use `get_or_create` to create an instance. Please check django doc about saving an object to learn more: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects